# Creating RRD's, Cant quite understand RRA's

Tags: monitoring, rrdtool, rrd

I am trying to use RRDtool to create some graphs for monitoring network traffic.

I understand how most of the config to create the RRD's works, but im a little lost on the RRA definitions.

I want to create RRA's for 1 Hour, 1 Day, 1 Week, 1 Month and 1 Year.

Im jsut not sure how to work out the numbers for the RRA definition, and the examples I have seen on the net dont really clear it up either, some say its to do with how many pixels wide your graph is, etc.. I am stuck.

I would like to take a reading every minute also.

Hope someone can help & Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers are relative to the base interval (step) of your rrd. So you first define how many base steps create one row in the RRA and then how many such rows should be kept.